# "Delete both brackets" keyboard shortcut in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom, when deleting the opening bracket or paren, is there a keyboard shortcut to delete the closing one along with it? (Kind of like how it auto-encloses when you select and then hit ', ], (, or {, but in reverse)?

For example:

```
 hi = function(|stuff, stuff2, stuff3){}
 //            ^ pretend that's my cursor and I hit delete/backspace.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default keybinding in Atom to remove matching brackets varies by operating system.
On Windows and Linux it is: `ctrl-alt-backspace`
On Mac it is: `ctrl-backspace`

To use these commands, position your cursor just after one of the brackets that you wish to remove (as if you were going to remove it with backspace), and then enter the command.

There is also a command to remove brackets from selection: `ctrl-]`
However, this keybinding is also used for the `indent-selected-rows` command, so it may not work for you unless you edit your keybindings to resolve the conflict.

All information is based on Atom 1.44.0.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The magic combo is ctrl+delete!

Comment: ctrl + alt + delete on windows

Comment: @Fab313 and Linux (Fedora) as well

Comment: It is ctrl + alt + backspace not delete

Comment: What about mac?

Comment: 'ctrl-delete' is the keybinding for 'delete-to-end-of-word' and does not remove matching brackets as of Atom 1.44.0.